# Problems when using cv::cuda::GpuMat with thrust and testing thrust API

Tags: c++, opencv, cuda, thrust

I want to pass cv::cuda::GpuMat to thrust function and I find [this function](https://answers.opencv.org/question/69891/using-thrust-with-cvcudagpumat/) which can be used for creating a thrust iterator that indexes a cv::cuda::GpuMat. I have 2 problems in the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<io.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>
#include<string>
#include<iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <vector> 
  
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include<thrust/functional.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/generate.h>
#include <thrust/sort.h>
#include <thrust/copy.h>

#include<opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include<cudaimgproc.hpp>
#include<opencv2/cudafilters.hpp>
#include<opencv2/cudaarithm.hpp>


template<typename T>
    struct greater_than_value_pred
    {
        T value;
    greater_than_value_pred(T value) : value(value) {}

    __host__ __device__
        bool operator()(T v) const { return v > value; }
};

    using namespace std;


    int main()
    {
        int compare_vari = 20;
    
    
        cv::cuda::GpuMat d_data_open(1, 100, CV_32SC2);
        // Thrust compatible begin and end iterators to channel 0 of this matrix
        auto idxBegin = GpuMatBeginItr<int>(d_data_open, 1);
        auto idxEnd = GpuMatEndItr<int>(d_data_open, 1);
        // Fill the index channel with a sequence of numbers from 0 to 100
        thrust::sequence(idxBegin, idxEnd);
        d_iter = thrust::find_if(idxBegin, idxEnd, greater_than_value_pred<int>(compare_vari));

        /*Use thrust::device_data to test */
        thrust::device_vector<int> d_thrust_data;
        thrust::device_vector<int>::iterator d_iter;
        thrust::sequence(d_thrust_data.begin(), d_thrust_data.end());
        d_iter = thrust::find_if(d_thrust_data.begin(), d_thrust_data.end(), greater_than_value_pred<int>(compare_vari));
        //std::cout << *d_iter << std::endl;
    }
```

Question 1:
This code cannot complie:   *`d_iter = thrust::find_if(idxBegin, idxEnd, greater_than_value_pred<double>(compare_vari));`*
Using idxBegin and idxEnd works well with thrust::sequence(), sort() and so on, but when applying them to thrust::find_if(), it will hint "no operator '=' matches these operands".

Question 2:

```
*//std::cout << *d_iter << std::endl;*
```

I want to check the result by the above code, but when debugging it says abort() has been called. I wonder if d_iter is in device memory, if so I need to copy it to host memory? But I don't know how to copy  iterator to the host memory.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> Question 2:

> *//std::cout << *d_iter << std::endl;*
> I want to check the result by the above code, but when debugging it says abort() has been called. I wonder if d_iter is in device memory, if so I need to copy it to host memory? But I don't know how to copy iterator to the host memory.

(You don't want to copy the *iterator* to host memory, what you desire is to copy *what the iterator points to* to host memory.)

The  issue here is that you are not giving any actual size to the `device_vector` in question:

```
    thrust::device_vector<int> d_thrust_data;
```

that creates an empty vector with no allocation.  Therefore no iterator referencing that vector will point to anything valid, because there is no allocation associated with that vector.  If we modify it to:

```
    thrust::device_vector<int> d_thrust_data(22);
```

we have now created a vector with 22 elements, and the rest of your code, including your `std::cout ...` statement, will then be sensible.  (21 or larger is also important because your `find_if` is looking for an element of value 20.)

The following code has the above issues addressed and seems to compile and run correctly for me:

```
$ cat t100.cu
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/functional.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/generate.h>
#include <thrust/sort.h>
#include <thrust/copy.h>


template<typename T>
    struct greater_than_value_pred
    {
        T value;
    greater_than_value_pred(T value) : value(value) {}

    __host__ __device__
        bool operator()(T v) const { return v > value; }
};

    using namespace std;


    int main()
    {
        int compare_vari = 20;

        /*Use thrust::device_data to test */
        thrust::device_vector<int> d_thrust_data(22);
        thrust::device_vector<int>::iterator d_iter;
        thrust::sequence(d_thrust_data.begin(), d_thrust_data.end());
        d_iter = thrust::find_if(d_thrust_data.begin(), d_thrust_data.end(), greater_than_value_pred<int>(compare_vari));
        std::cout << *d_iter << std::endl;
    }
$ nvcc -o t100 t100.cu
$ ./t100
21
$
```

Comment: Thanks your help. I am sorry that I found I put the wrong code in Question 1,  `d_iter = thrust::find_if(d_thrust_data.begin(), d_thrust_data.end(), greater_than_value_pred(compare_vari)) `can compile. it is `d_iter = thrust::find_if(idxBegin, idxEnd, greater_than_value_pred<double>(compare_vari)); `cannot compile. The idxBegin and idxEnd which I used from [link](https://answers.opencv.org/question/69891/using-thrust-with-cvcudagpumat/)here go wrong when using thrust::find_if().  I have changed my post.

Comment: Did you try changing the predicate type from `double` to `int` ?

Comment: Yes, I have changed the type following your post, and Question 2 is solved.

Comment: I mean did you change this: `d_iter = thrust::find_if(idxBegin, idxEnd, greater_than_value_pred<double>(compare_vari)); `  to this: `d_iter = thrust::find_if(idxBegin, idxEnd, greater_than_value_pred<int>(compare_vari)); `

Comment: Yes, I have changed to this and tried, but it cannot compile with an error no operator '=' matches these operands.

Comment: I just tried when using `double` predicate, `d_iter = thrust::find_if(d_thrust_data.begin(), d_thrust_data.end(), greater_than_value_pred<double>(compare_vari));`  still works with right result 21. So I think it is not the predicate type problem.